# Some advice on studying math on a graduate level (postgrad)

Tags: education, advice, career-development

I studied some math and stats as an Undergraduate (up to Multivariable calc/statistics, Linear Algebra, and Real Analysis) but majored in Economics.

Unfortunately, I realised a little too late that this is what I want to study as a graduate student (for career and interest reasons). It seems that I do not have a sufficient background because my principal degree was not in mathematics to be accepted into a reputable graduate programme.

Does anybody have any advice on how to move forward to study Mathematics at a graduate level? Are there any extra enhancement courses that I can take to improve my background?

I live in London.

Comment: get a math undergrad degree?

Comment: Some coursework masters program may be suitable

Comment: Check the entrance requirements, some courses may be more open, particularly these days for masters degrees. You could also do an economics by research masters masters degree, and do a particularly mathematical project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm studying Post-Grad Maths with the OU at the moment.  In order to be accepted onto the MSc path you need a degree in Maths or I think you can sit an MSc Entry Test...  but I believe you have to show a certain level of Mathematical content in any Undergraduate course before you can do that.

I also looked into doing an MSc via distant learning from a variety of other UK based Universities and I'm afraid you need a degree in Maths or an undergraduate qualification with a significant amount of Mathematical content (at the right level) before you can progress.

To be fair though, I think that is only right as lets be honest, without a solid foundation... eventually everything falls down.

In short, I think you will just have to study Undergraduate Maths to gain the correct pre-requisites for Grauduate study.